# The Garbage Disposal is still parented to the old domain

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Our trash room, [The Garbage Disposal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146140/the-garbage-disposal), is still parented to https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com, not https://langdev.stackexchange.com. As @Catija said [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64166120#64166120):

> it's parented to a site that doesn't exist any more, so we can't reparent it to the current site name.

Comment: Why not chuck the Garbage Disposal into a bigger garbage disposal and make a new room with the current domain?

Comment: That's certainly an option, @user and it would likely be faster and easier. It kinda depends on how many messages would need to be moved. If y'all go that route and need my help, let me know.

Comment: If moving messages would be required, that's probably not a great option. Every single one would have that little arrow next to it

Comment: While that's true, it's also a trash can, right? So do you actually care that much, @RydwolfPrograms?

Comment: Either way, wouldn't it still be a bug that Lyxal managed to lock himself out?

Comment: @Catija Ah, I misread which room we were talking about

Comment: @Bbrk24 it depends. If I understand what you mean by locked out, I'm leaning towards not. Assuming my memory is correct, the system restricts reparenting chat rooms to require the person is a mod on the current parent site. Despite what Area 51 says, lyxal isn't a mod on that site (and neither am I, for that matter). So it's probably working correctly, in the most base sense of correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old room has been renamed to make it clear that it's no longer to be used.

All messages in the old room have been moved to a new room parented properly.

The new room has all the room owners of the old room added.

New room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147825/the-garbage-disposal